# How can I convert a human-readable number to a computer-readable number in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm working in Ruby with an array that contains a series of numbers in human-readable format (e.g., 2.5B, 1.27M, 600,000, where "B" stands for billion, "M" stands for million). I'm trying to convert all elements of the array to the same format.

Here is the code I've written:

```
array.each do |elem|
    if elem.include? 'B'
        elem.slice! "B"
        elem = elem.to_f
        elem = (elem * 1000000000)
    else if elem.include? 'M'
        elem.slice! "M"
        elem = elem.to_f
        elem = (elem * 1000000)
    end
end
```

When I inspect the elements of the array using `puts(array)`, however, the numbers appear with the "B" and "M" sliced off but the multiplication conversion does not appear to have been applied (e.g., the numbers now read 2.5, 1.27, 600,000, instead of 2500000000, 1270000, 600,000).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's a good question.  The slice! works because it changes the array element, but assingment `elem = ...` you are now referencing a different object.  See @Thilo's answer below for a good alternative.

Comment: You need to provide an input array sample. Don't make people invent the input.

Comment: If you found any of the answers helpful, please select the one that was most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Another variation:

```
array = ['2.5B', '1.27M', '$600000']

p array.each_with_object([]) { |i, a|
  i = i.gsub('$', '')
  a << if i.include? 'B'
    i.to_f * 1E9
  elsif i.include? 'M'
    i.to_f * 1E6
  else
    i.to_f
  end
}
```

`#=> [2500000000.0, 1270000.0, 600000.0]`

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note is that `else if` in ruby is `elsif`. See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm

Here is a working function for you to try out:

```
def convert_array_items_from_human_to_integers(array)

    array.each_with_index do |elem,i|
        if elem.include? 'B'
            elem.slice! "B"
            elem = elem.to_f
            elem = (elem * 1000000000)
        elsif elem.include? 'M'
            elem.slice! "M"
            elem = elem.to_f
            elem = (elem * 1000000)
        end
        array[i] = elem
    end

    return array 

end
```

Calling `convert_array_items_from_human_to_integers(["2.5B", "1.2M"])`

returns `[2500000000.0, 1200000.0]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
array.map do |elem|
    elem = elem.gsub('$','')
    if elem.include? 'B'
        elem.to_f * 1000000000
    elsif elem.include? 'M'
        elem.to_f * 1000000
    else
        elem.to_f
    end
end
```

This uses `map` instead of `each` to return a new array. Your attempt assigns copies of the array elements, leaving the original array in place (except for the `slice!`, which modifies in place). You can dispense with the slicing in the first place, since `to_f` will simply ignore any non-numeric characters.

EDIT:

If you have leading characters such as `$2.5B`, as your question title indicates (but not your example), you'll need to strip those explicitly. But your sample code doesn't handle those either, so I assume that's not an issue.

Comment: `"$2.5B".to_f # => 0.0`

Comment: @user3814019, also array could be replaced with new elements with `map!`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on pjs' answer:

```
array.each do |elem|
```

`elem` is a local variable pointing to each array element, one at a time.  When you do this:

```
        elem.slice! "B"
```

you are sending a message to that array element telling it to slice the B.  And you're seeing that in the end result.  But when you do this:

```
        elem = elem.to_f
```

now you've reassigned your local variable `elem` to something completely new.  You haven't reassigned what's in the array, just what `elem` is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd go about it:

```
ARY = %w[2.5B 1.27M 600,000]

def clean_number(s)
  s.gsub(/[^\d.]+/, '')
end


ARY.map{ |v|

  case v
  when /b$/i
    clean_number(v).to_f * 1_000_000_000
  when /m$/i
    clean_number(v).to_f * 1_000_000
  else
    clean_number(v).to_f
  end

}
# => [2500000000.0, 1270000.0, 600000.0]
```

The guts of the code are in the `case` statement. A simple check for the multiplier allows me to strip the undesired characters and multiply by the right value.

Normally we could use `to_f` to find the floating-point number to be multiplied for strings like '1.2', but it breaks down for things like '$1.2M' because of the "$". The same thing is true for embedded commas marking thousands:

```
'$1.2M'.to_f # => 0.0
'1.2M'.to_f # => 1.2
'6,000'.to_f # => 6.0
'6000'.to_f # => 6000.0
```

To fix the problem for simple strings containing just the value, it's not necessary to do anything fancier than stripping undesirable characters using `gsub(/[^\d.]+/, '')`:

```
'$1.2M'.gsub(/[^\d.]+/, '') # => "1.2"
'1.2M'.gsub(/[^\d.]+/, '') # => "1.2"
'6,000'.gsub(/[^\d.]+/, '') # => "6000"
'6000'.gsub(/[^\d.]+/, '') # => "6000"
```

`[^\d.]` means "anything *NOT* a digit or `'.'`.

Be careful how you convert your decimal values to integers. You could end up throwing away important precision:

```
 '0.2M'.gsub(/[^\d.]+/, '').to_f * 1_000_000 # => 200000.0
 '0.2M'.gsub(/[^\d.]+/, '').to_i * 1_000_000 # => 0
('0.2M'.gsub(/[^\d.]+/, '').to_f * 1_000_000).to_i  # => 200000
```

Of course all this breaks down if your string is more complex than a simple number and multiplier. It's easy to break down a string and identify those sort of sub-strings, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

**Code**

```
T, M, B = 1_000, 1_000_000, 1_000_000_000

def convert(arr)
  arr.map do |n|
    m = n.gsub(/[^\d.TMB]/,'')
    m.to_f * (m[-1][/[TMB]/] ? Object.const_get(m[-1]) : 1)
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = %w[$2.5B 1.27M 22.5T, 600,000]
convert(arr)    
  # => [2500000000.0, 1270000.0, 22500.0, 600000.0]
```

**Explanation**

The line

```
m = n.gsub(/[^\d.TMB]/,'')
  # => ["2.5B", "1.27M", "22.5T", "600000"]
```

merely eliminates unwanted characters.

```
  m.to_f * (m[-1][/[TMB]/] ? Object.const_get(m[-1]) : 1)
```

returns the product of the string converted to a float and a constant given by the last character of the string, if that character is `T`, `M` or `B`, else `1`.

Actual implementation might be like this:

```
class A
  T, M, B = 1_000, 1_000_000, 1_000_000_000
  def doit(arr)
    c = self.class.constants.map(&:to_s).join
    arr.map do |n|
      m = n.gsub(/[^\d.#{c}]/,'')
      m.to_f * (m[-1][/[#{c}]/] ? self.class.const_get(m[-1]) : 1)
    end
  end
end
```

If we wished to change the reference for 1,000 from `T` to `K` and add `T` for trillion, we would need only change

```
  T, M, B = 1_000, 1_000_000, 1_000_000_000
```

to

```
  K, M, B, T = 1_000, 1_000_000, 1_000_000_000, 1_000_000_000_000
```