# How to convert human readable number to actual number in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a simple Rails/Ruby helper function to help you convert human readable numbers to actual numbers?

Such as:

```
1K => 1000

2M => 2,000,000

2.2K => 2200

1,500 => 1500

50 => 50

5.5M => 5500000
```

Comment: How about converting it by yourself ? `K=10^3`, `M=10^6` and so on. If there is no suffix just print the number else multiply it by equivalent value and print it.

Comment: `2,000,000` is not a valid ruby `Numeric`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
test = {
  '1K' => 1000,
  '2M' => 2000000,
  '2.2K' => 2200,
  '1,500' => 1500,
  '50' => 50, 
  '5.5M' => 5500000
}

class String
  def human_readable_to_i
    multiplier = {'K' => 1_000, 'M' => 1_000_000}[self.upcase[/[KM](?=\z)/]] || 1
    value = self.gsub(/[^\d.]/, '')
    case value.count('.')
    when 0 then value.to_i
    when 1 then value.to_f
    else 0
    end * multiplier
  end 
end

test.each { |k, v| raise "Test failed" unless k.human_readable_to_i == v  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this if you have an array of human readable numbers than

```
array.map do |elem|
    elem = elem.gsub('$','')
    if elem.include? 'B'
        elem.to_f * 1000000000
    elsif elem.include? 'M'
        elem.to_f * 1000000
    elsif elem.include? 'K'
        elem.to_f * 1000
    else
        elem.to_f
    end
end
```

Have a look here as well, you will find many Numbers Helpers

[NumberHelper Rails.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html)

[Ruby Array human readable to actual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620018/how-can-i-convert-a-human-readable-number-to-a-computer-readable-number-in-ruby)

Comment: `elem = elem.gsub('$','')` :: yeah, there are no currencies in the world save for USD.